# How to retrieve all arguments used in a method on a page from another page?

Tags: php, parsing, translate

I am not sure if I just have a bad structure for my code or this is a problem not normally found, but I don't even know how to start looking for a solution for my problem. I have my own simple translation script which is called like this:

```
<?php echo $Translate->text("Name"); ?>
```

It would return (and echo) a string with a keyword 'Name'. The problem is, for several reasons (name: misstranslations, report, development, translation in situ), I might want to retrieve all strings' keywords that are on a page. A simple page (example.com/campus/index.php) looks like this:

```
<h1> <?php echo $Translate->text(Campus); ?> </h1>

<p style="text-align:justify;">
  <?php echo $Translate->text(126); ?>
</p>

<p style="text-align:justify;">
  <?php echo $Translate->text(129); ?>
</p>

<a href="<?php $Link->create("campus/about"); ?>">
  <h2 class="bodymenu"><?php echo $Translate->text(About); ?> </h2>
</a>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
  <?php echo $Translate->text(146); ?>
</p>

<a href="<?php $Link->create("campus/learning_center"); ?>">
  <h2 class="bodymenu"><?php echo $Translate->text(Learning_center); ?> </h2>
</a>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
  <?php echo $Translate->text(147); ?>
</p>

<a href="<?php $Link->create("campus/residence"); ?>">
  <h2 class="bodymenu"><?php echo $Translate->text(Residence); ?> </h2>
</a>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
  <?php echo $Translate->text(128); ?>
</p>
```

And I would like to obtain in some situations: `$Translations=array("Campus","126","129","About","146","Learning_center","147","Residence","128");` for further processing (EDIT) **from another page**.

In some cases there's much more php logic mixed in the page, in some others it's like this. There's much more logic code and classes that it's included automatically before and after every page. So, basically, I'd like to know (for this example but being able to extend it) how could I retrieve all the keywords.

I am thinking about 2 methods basically, but I don't think either is optimal. First would be to parse the php code as is using regex. Since I know the bits that I'm looking for, I thing it would be possible. Second one is that, depending on a SESSION variable, I render the html and parse it, so the `echo $Translate->text(Campus);` would return something like `<span id="Translation">Campus</span>` and then parse only the html and retrieve all the ids. Can you think about any other way to retrieve the ids before I get on this?.

PS, I **DON'T** want to hardcode all the id's in an array at the beginning or end of a page.

Comment: Must I read Translate as: making the page available in multiple languages like english and German?

Comment: Yes, `$Translate=new Translate($User->Language);` is for processing translations. Then, `$Translate->text('key')` translates an specific keyword into a string in the correct language which is already set.

Comment: Ok: why not use the gettext extension?

Comment: Don't parse html with regex if you can avoid it. Best use the [DOM](http://php.net/dom) to get your elements by id.

Comment: @JvdBerg , I'm learning PHP so I'd like to learn it well enough before getting with more professional solutions. For almost every class that I can imagine there should be an already implemented class solution. But if I got to use them, I wouldn't know how they actually work, I would only know how to use them.

I have downloaded and printed CakePHP cookbook for reading, studying and consulting in the near future, when I have a more solid base.

Comment: @vascowhite that's exactly why I asked the question, because, somehow (lot of time in SO probably), I know that it's not good idea to parse html with regex.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos See my answer below. If you are learning, do not reinvent the weel. Do not use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel by implementing a translating system. The [gettext extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) is there for painless, on the fly, language switching.

Basicly you write your site in a default language:

```
<?php echo _("Name"); ?>
```

Do not write `<?php echo $Translate->text(147); ?>`, noboby knows what that is. Write:

<`?php echo _("Learning Centre"); ?>`

For managing translations there is a choice of editors for Windows, Linux and Mac, [POEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) for example.

Switching to a different language is easy:

```
public function SetDomain( $path )
{
    define( 'DOMAIN', 'messages' );
    bindtextdomain( DOMAIN, $path );
    bind_textdomain_codeset( DOMAIN, "UTF-8" );
    textdomain( DOMAIN );
}
```

**note:** if you set short_open_tags to on you can write:

```
<?= _("Name"); ?>
```

Comment: Should that be <?php echo "_('Name')"; ?>? That syntax doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: No the echo _("Name");`` part, I'm sure that syntax is incorrect, it will give you a fatal error, call to undefined function _(). It should be `<?php echo "_('Name')"; ?>` or `<?= "_('Name')"; ?>`.

Comment: Ahh .. that is part of the gettext extension: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

Comment: I see, the function name is actually `_()`. And the devs wonder why PHP has a bad name!

Comment: How is this even an answer to the *actual question I was asking*? I know about gettext and I have reasons to use my personal solution, with the comment and a link about a bad practice it would be enough. If you want to make it an actual answer to my question, how would you retrieve all the passed keywords to gettext on a page from a different page?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos Calm down, people here are trying to help you.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos You do not have to do that yourself, POEdit does the job for you.

Comment: @vascowhite , I wasn't in a bad mood nor I'm native but from only text it's difficult to see that... I'm sorry if I sounded like that! And thank you JvdBerg for pointing all of that out.
Now I think that's a good answer. I hope I can upvote it after the small edit I did (:

Answer (score 0):

if i understood it correct,

modify your Translate class a little: add a variable which will collect all the strings you are using, like:

```
public $aStrings = array();
```

then, add in your function text($arg) something like:

```
$this->aStrings[] = $arg;
```

then you will have all the strings on page in your Translate->aStrings variable, then to print it use somethin like:

```
print_r($Translate->aStrings);
```

Comment: Sorry I was confusing, added an small edit. I want to retrieve all the keywords from a DIFFERENT page. For example, from example.com/translate/?page=campus I'd like to retrieve all the keywords in the page example.com/campus.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `Translate` class with one that collects the values in an array, then use that in your page:

```
class MyTranslate extends Translate {
  public $texts = array();
  public function text($which) {
    $this->texts[] = $which;
    return parent::text($which);
  }
}

$Translate=new MyTranslate($User->Language);

ob_start();
require('/path/to/other/page');
ob_end_clean();

var_dump($Translate->texts);
```

Comment: See my other comment: I want to retrieve all the keywords from a DIFFERENT page. For example, from example.com/translate/?page=campus I'd like to retrieve all the keywords in the page example.com/campus.

Comment: You can `require` the other page after defining your own `$Translate`.  Use output buffering to get rid of any output it may produce.  I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

***Create 2 file in english folder. ( You can specify it later but usually location for languages file in languages directory )***
***campus.about.php***:

```
<?php
$lang["Name"]               = "Name";
$lang["Address"]            = "Address";    
?>
```

***campus.learning_center.php***:

```
<?php
$lang["Learning"]               = "Learning";
$lang["Residence"]          = "Residence";  
?>
```

**Your Class Translate File ( root directory )**:

```
class Translate {

    public $_text= array(); // Change it into private properties coz you create 
// text method for get the value, I set it public just for easy to debug it.
    private $_language;

    function __construct($language){ // Set Language
        $this->_language= $language;
    }

    public function create($page){ // Get Language File
        // $page= campus/about change into this campus.about
        // Get language file Ex: english/campus.about.php
        require($this->_language.'/'.$page.'.php');
        $this->_text= array_merge($this->_text, $lang);
    }

    public function text($text){ // Display Keywords
        echo $this->_text[$text];
    }
}
$Translate= new Translate('english');
$Translate->create('campus.about');
print_r($Translate->_text);
$Translate->create('campus.learning_center');
print_r($Translate->_text);
```